# what's the diff between these two calls of static template class member function?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, non-type

I'm experimenting with non-type template parameters and have run into a compiler error I cannot understand, let alone address.

I want one of the members of my template class to be static. For whatever reason, I can successfully call a static class member function from within `main()` but not before it as shown here:

```
enum class PrimeBits {
    Two = 2,
    Three = 2,
    Five = 3,
    Seven = 3,
    Eleven = 4
};

template <typename T, enum PrimeBits P>
class wibble {
    public:

        wibble() {};

        static void nBits () {
            std::cout << "Bits: " << static_cast<int>(P) << std::endl;
        }
};

wibble<int, PrimeBits::Eleven>::nBits();        // compiler error
// specializing member 'wibble<int, (PrimeBits)4>::nBits' requires 'template<>' syntax

int main () {

    wibble<int, PrimeBits::Eleven>::nBits();        // compiles & runs ok 

}
```

this is with gcc version 7.3.0 with the -std=gnu++17 set.

Comment: You cannot call anything from the global scope (aside from initializing global variables).

Comment: Thanks! I feel like rephrasing my question to “why is this compiler error message so unhelpful?”

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call method before `main`, you might use global variable:
As your method return `void`, using comma operator to be able to initialize a variable:

```
static const auto dummy = (wibble<int, PrimeBits::Eleven>::nBits(), 0);
```

Comment: Thanks. This is cunning workaround code. I think CurlyBracket provided the answer I’d give the check mark to.